# How to add background images to blocks?

Tags: 7, blocks

How to upload background images to blocks individually ?

Is there any contributed modules available uploading background images to blocks?

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Background Images Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter) module

> This module provides an image formatter who allows you to set an image in background of a div.
>
> The images are from a field of an entity and not from a configuration page or sth else, so it's very easy to setup and manage.

This can be done using Views. Create a **block**, select the "Background Image" formatter for your image field, save, place the block, boom, you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I found this module  [ST Block](http://codecanyon.net/item/st-block/8537636).

> ST Block is a drupal module allow you easy configure block with very much options as set block id, block animation, block background image, block background video, block background parallax,...